# How to concatenate many rows with same id in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table contains the details like with two fields:

```
ID      DisplayName
1        Editor
1        Reviewer
7        EIC
7        Editor
7        Reviewer
7        Editor
19       EIC
19       Editor
19       Reviewer
```

I want get the unique details with DisplayName like

`1 Editor,Reviewer 7 EIC,Editor,Reviewer`

Don't get duplicate value with ID 7

How to combine DisplayName Details? How to write the Query?

Comment: Which one is it? mysql or sql-server?

Comment: @sagi: I mean sql server

Comment: You want to have 2 columns as for now? `ID` and `DisplayName` just for the same id you want comma separate names? Or you want to get all results in one row as you wrote?

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas: I would like get all result but I don't need get duplicate value. ID = 7 I have 2 Editor but I would like get one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In *SQL-Server* you can do it in the following:

**QUERY**

```
SELECT id, displayname = 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + displayname
           FROM #t b 
           WHERE b.id = a.id 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM #t a
GROUP BY id
```

**TEST DATA**

```
create table #t 
(
id int,
displayname nvarchar(max)
)

insert into #t values    
 (1 ,'Editor')
,(1 ,'Reviewer')
,(7 ,'EIC')
,(7 ,'Editor')
,(7 ,'Reviewer')
,(7 ,'Editor')
,(19,'EIC')
,(19,'Editor')
,(19,'Reviewer')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id  displayname
1   Editor, Reviewer
7   Editor, EIC, Reviewer
19  Editor, EIC, Reviewer
```

Comment: what does `, 1, 2, ''` means after the stuff?

Comment: @guradio this is to remove the leading comma and space that would otherwise appear. They are arguments for [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): start = 1, length = 2, replacement value = '', ie. the **first two** characters are replaced with **''**

Answer (score 11):

**SQL Server 2017+ and SQL Azure: STRING_AGG**

Starting with the next version of SQL Server, we can finally concatenate across rows without having to resort to any variable or XML witchery.

[STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT ID, STRING_AGG(DisplayName, ', ') AS DisplayNames
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: how to avoid duplications using this method. So for example in ID 7, instead of EIC, Editor, Reviewer, Editor how to get it as EIC, Editor, Reviewer without duplicating Editor?

Answer (score 10):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    DisplayName VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO @t (ID, DisplayName)
VALUES
    (1 , 'Editor'),
    (1 , 'Reviewer'),
    (7 , 'EIC'),
    (7 , 'Editor'),
    (7 , 'Reviewer'),
    (7 , 'Editor'),
    (19, 'EIC'),
    (19, 'Editor'),
    (19, 'Reviewer')

SELECT *, STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + DisplayName
            FROM @t
            WHERE ID = t.ID
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID
    FROM @t
) t
```

Output -

```
----------- ------------------------
1           Editor, Reviewer
7           Editor, EIC, Reviewer
19          Editor, EIC, Reviewer
```

My post about string aggregation:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691102/String-Aggregation-in-the-World-of-SQL-Server

Comment: what does `, 1, 2, ''` means after the stuff?

Comment: Finally got it to work with this sample. Just replace @t with a subselect that look like the temp table and it'll just work!

Answer (score 9):

For MySQL:
`SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(displayname) FROM tableName GROUP BY id`

Refer: http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/group_concat

Comment: SQL-Server does not support this notation.

Comment: Thanks, works very well. I wish we could change the separator!

Answer (score 3):

and in case of oracle database

```
select id, 
       listagg(displayname, ',') within group (order by displayname) as names
from test
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

to change the separator use

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(displayname SEPARATOR ';') FROM tableName GROUP BY id
```

this will change separator from comma to semicolon :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,

```
SELECT Distinct
    t1.ID,
    MAX(STUFF(t2.x_id,1,1,'')) AS DisplayName
FROM Table t1
CROSS apply(
    SELECT Distinct ', ' + SUBSTRING(t2.DisplayName,1,2)
    FROM Table t2
    WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.DisplayName > ''
    FOR xml PATH('')
) AS t2 (x_id)
GROUP BY
    t1.ID
order by 1
GO
```

Comment: Just so you know. When there are alot of rows in the table, this method is will be much slower than Devart's and Stan's answers

Comment: what does `, 1, 2, ''` means after the stuff?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle SQL, you can use `LISTAGG`.

```sql
SELECT ID, LISTAGG(DisplayName, ', ') as all_agg
FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY ID;
```