# Select Statement pulls values from a junction table into 1 comma delimited string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query that is selecting the "CategoryName" from my Junction table and Category table.

```
SELECT CategoryName 
FROM BND_ListingJunction_testing j
JOIN BND_ListingCategories c ON c.CatID = j.Junc_CatID
WHERE j.Junc_LID = 3
```

In SQL this works fine and displays X rows for any category that LID matches in my junction table.

My web application however is only reading the 1st result when creating a token. Is it possible to pull the result set for X rows and display them all in 1 row just comma delimited.

For example: if LID=1 has been categories 5 times the above query will return 5 rows one for each category that exists in my junction table.

I'd like to have a result set that looks something like this (in one column):

```
 Category1, Category2, Category3, Category4, Category5
```

Instead of:

```
1   Category1
2   Category2
3   Category3
4   Category4
5   Category5
```

Again I'm using 5 as an example a record can have anywhere from 1-X categories.

---UPDATE

I've tried the following that seems to work but does not add a , between the results only 1 at the beginning.

```
Declare @Cats as Nvarchar(max) = ','
Select @Cats = @Cats + CategoryName
From BND_ListingJunction_testing j
JOIN BND_ListingCategories c on c.CatID = j.Junc_CatID
Where j.Junc_LID = 3

Print(@Cats)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate many rows with same id in sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172956/how-to-concatenate-many-rows-with-same-id-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server, you can use the XML PATH statement to convert multiple rows into a serial string aggregate.

Postgres has a 'string_agg()' aggregate function that is much easier to use.

Comment: If I add `FOR XML Path` at the end of my query how can I remove the <row> & <CategoryName> & </row> & </CategoryName> tags just so it displays values?

Comment: You haven't shown any of your web application code, so your question isn't really addressable.  In fact, it sounds like a very different question than the one about concatenating rows.

Comment: My web application just gives me an area to insert a SQL query. When using SQL Management studio if I add `FOR XML Path` it does combine all rows into one but adds XML formatting where I just want values in a comma delimited string.

Comment: You need more than just "FOR XML PATH" to generate a comma-delimited string.  Numerous examples can be found with a web search.  Here's one: https://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/

Comment: thanks for your input the link has both the category & sub-category in my case I just need the subcategories going to try and modify their example for my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This accomplished my desired result.

```
SELECT CategoryName + ', ' AS [text()] 
FROM BND_ListingJunction_testing j
JOIN BND_ListingCategories c on c.CatID = j.Junc_CatID
WHERE Junc_LID=2
FOR XML PATH ('')
```