# SQL - string combine based on id

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need suggestion to split string in table 1, match its Ids with table 2 and concatenate the values.

Table - 1

```
Id  Tbl1Col
1   2
2   2,4
3   
4   6
5   3
```

Table - 2

```
Id  Tbl2Col
1   E
2   F
3   M
4   U
5   P
6   C
7   N
8   G
```

Query -

```
SELECT T2.Tbl2Col
FROM Table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2 WHERE T1.Tbl1Col= T2.Id
WHERE T1.Id = @Id
```

Now If `@Id = 1`, Output is `F` -- works fine

Now If `@Id = 2`, Output should be `FU` -- should not be `F,U`

Comment: You need an ON clause, where you put the join condition.

Comment: You should **not** be storing comma separated values in the database

Comment: Add the expected result as well. (Formatted text here too.)

Comment: @James Z,  I didn't create these tables, have to work with them anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuck!  But you can use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT T2.Tbl2Col
FROM Table1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 T2
     WHERE ',' + T1.Tbl1Col + ',' LIKE '%,' + CAST(T2.Id as VARCHAR(255)) + ',%'
WHERE T1.Id = @Id;
```

You have a lousy data format, so this cannot make use of indexes.  You should really have a separate table, with one row per `Table1.id` and `Table2.id`.  Such a table is called a junction table or an association table.

Comment: I understand normalization, have to work with this data format. Let me test this.

Comment: Had to `select @Codes = concat(@codes + T2.Tbl2Col)` to get the desired result as `FU` rather than in multiple rows. Still, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
create table dbo.Table01 (
Id int
, Col varchar(100)
);

create table dbo.Table02 (
Id int
, Col varchar(100)
);

insert into dbo.Table01 (Id, Col)
values (1, '2'), (2, '2, 4');

insert into dbo.Table02 (Id, Col)
values (1, 'E'), (2, 'F'), (4, 'U');

select
t.Id
, replace(STRING_AGG (t02.Col, ','), ',', '') as StringAgg
from dbo.Table01 t
cross apply string_split (t.Col, ',') as ss
inner join dbo.Table02 t02 on ss.value = t02.Id
group by t.id
```

Comment: Your code is not working ! **Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 19
'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.**

Comment: On which SQL Server version are you on?

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader, yes this is true. You can use custom functions for string aggs. Then it works on SQL 2016+. Also if you need to work on SQL 2014- then use custom function for string_split.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the next approach:-

1) Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows via using `CROSS APPLY` with `XML`

2) Join the two tables with left join.

3) Concatenate many rows with same id via using `STUFF` & `FOR XML`

4) Use Replace function for removing comma.

**Demo:-**

```
declare @MyTable table (id int , Tbl1Col varchar(10))
insert into @MyTable values (1,'2'),(2,'2,4'),(3,''),(4,'6'),(5,'3')

declare @MyTable2 table (id int , Tbl2Col varchar(10))
insert into @MyTable2 values (1,'E'),(2,'F'),(3,'M'),(4,'U'),(5,'P'),(6,'C'),(7,'N'),(8,'G')


select a.id , Tbl2Col
into #TestTable
from 
(

SELECT A.id,  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Tbl1Col  
 FROM  
 (
     SELECT id,  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Tbl1Col, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
     FROM  @MyTable
 ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a) ) a

 left join @MyTable2 b
 on a.Tbl1Col = b.id

order by a.id



SELECT id, Tbl2Col = 
    Replace(STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Tbl2Col
           FROM #TestTable b 
           WHERE b.id = a.id 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),',','')
FROM #TestTable a
GROUP BY id
```

**Output:-**

```
1   F
2   F U
3   NULL
4   C
5   M
```

References:-

[Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

[How to concatenate many rows with same id in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172956/how-to-concatenate-many-rows-with-same-id-in-sql)

---

## Finally:-

***Don't use this approach, and normalize your database instead , just use it as fun/training/trying .... etc code.***

Comment: Tables were created by other devs few years back, I cannot alter them, well because of dependencies. I will test your solution too, seems interesting!