# How can I sum strings in one column into one row in Microsoft SQL? Group by does not work since it is MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

for example we have table with three columns

```
Column A |  Column B | Column C
-------------------------------
P1       |    10     |    A    
P1       |    20     |    B
P1       |    30     |    C
P2       |    30     |    D
P2       |    40     |    E
```

How do I have to write SELECT query in **Microsoft SQL** to have this kind of result

```
Column A |     Column B      |   Column C
------------------------------------------
P1       |    10, 20, 30     |    A, B, C
P2       |    30, 40         |    D, E
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate many rows with same id in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172956/how-to-concatenate-many-rows-with-same-id-in-sql)

Comment: go for `listagg` and partion by ColumnA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Wanderer, this is MSSQL. So group by wont work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(ColumnA VARCHAR(10),ColumnB INT ,ColumnC VARCHAR(10))
--insert rows

SELECT t.[ColumnA] ,
         [ColumnB] = STUFF((SELECT  ','+cast([ColumnB] AS VARCHAR ) FROM  #Temp WHERE  [ColumnA]  = t.[ColumnA]  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),
         [ColumnC] = STUFF((SELECT  ','+[ColumnC] FROM #Temp WHERE [ColumnA] = t.[ColumnA] FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM #Temp t
GROUP BY t.[ColumnA]
```

i test it

[image: result]

Answer (score 5):

If you are running SQL Server 2017, T-SQL enhancements introduced to SQL developers include the [STRING_AGG string concatenation function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/string-aggregation-function-to-concatenate-in-sql-server-2017.aspx)

You can simply use following SELECT statement for aggregating string values from different rows into a single column value

```
select
    ColumnA,
    string_agg(ColumnB,',') ColumnB,
    string_agg(ColumnC,',') ColumnC
from TestTable1
group by ColumnA
```

[image]

Comment: I am running Sql server 2014 :( Thanks for the tip. I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 1):

You could try `xml` method with `stuff()`  function

```
select t.[Column A] ,
         [Column B] = 
                stuff(
                       (select  ','+cast([Column B] as varchar) from <table> where [Column A]  = t.[Column A]  for xml path('')),
                       1,1,''),
         [Column C] = stuff(
                       (select  ','+[Column C] from <table> where [Column A] = t.[Column A] for xml path('')),
                       1,1,'')
from <table> t
group by t.[Column A]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLA,
      STUFF((select ', '+ColB from T1 AS B where A.ColA=B.ColA FOR XML PATH(''),Type).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS ColB,
      STUFF((select ', '+ColC from T1 AS B where A.ColA=B.ColA FOR XML PATH(''),Type).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS ColC

      FROM T1 A
```